# Subset pandas dataframe using function applied to a column/series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda, subset

I have a pandas dataframe `df` that I would like to subset based on the result of running `Name` through a certain function `is_valid()`

```
import pandas as pd

data = [['foo', 10], ['baar', 15], ['baz', 14]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['name', 'age'])
df

    name    age
0   foo     10
1   baar    15
2   baz     14
```

The function checks if the length of the input string is 3 and returns either True or False:

```
def is_valid(x):
    assert isinstance(x, str)
    return True if len(x) == 3 else False
```

My goal is to subset `df` where this function returns True, which would return an output of

```
    name    age
0   foo     10
2   baz     14
```

The following syntax returns an error; what is the correct syntax for applying a function to values of a column (series) and subsetting a dataframe if the output meets a condition (in this case = True) ?

```
df[is_valid(df['name'])]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.len`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.len.html) with [`Series.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html) for mask:

```
df = df[df['name'].str.len().eq(3)]
```

Or use [`Series.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html) for pass custom function:

```
df = df[df['name'].apply(is_valid)]
print (df)
  name  age
0  foo   10
2  baz   14
```

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
df[df['name'].str.len()==3]
```

Or use your code with `apply`:

```
df[df['name'].apply(is_valid)]
```